# Failed to repack resources After adding google play game service

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, google-play-games

I have added [ConsoliAds](https://portal.consoliads.com/download) plugin to my project and i can build android properly. But when I add Google Play Game plugin, during the build process I got **Failed to re-package resources**

**There is an image before adding google play games**

[image: There is an image before adding google play games]

**There is an image after adding google play game**

[image: There is an image after adding google play game]

During the build process I got **Failed to re-package resources** and these logs appear in the console.
I'm using the latest version of ConsoliAds and Google Play Game

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
D:\ANDROID\AndroidSDK\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "D:/ANDROID/AndroidSDK\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.chartboost.sdk.unity:com.google.unity:com.heyzap:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.Company.ProductName:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:com.papata.btb:com.unity3d.ads -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.0.4\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-base-11.0.4\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-11.0.4\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-11.0.4\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-11.0.4\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-ui-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-utils-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-fragment-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-media-compat-25.2.0\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.0.0\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res" -S "E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityAds\res"

stderr[
E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.0.4\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').

E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.0.4\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml:16: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18').

E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.0.4\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').

]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: D:\ANDROID\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-23\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=app_banner.png
trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png
Processing image: res\drawable\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable\app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
Processing image: res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png
Processing image: res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png: 98% size of source)
Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
Processing image: res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
Processing image: res\drawable-xxxhdpi\app_icon.png
    (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
    (processed image res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
    (processed image res\drawable-xxxhdpi\app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
    (new resource id app_banner from xhdpi-v4\drawable\app_banner.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from ldpi-v4\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from hdpi-v4\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from xhdpi-v4\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from xxhdpi-v4\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id app_icon from xxxhdpi-v4\drawable\app_icon.png #generated)
    (new resource id common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal from E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.0.4\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml)
    (new resource id common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled from E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.0.4\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml)
    (new resource id common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal from E:\Hashtomin2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-11.0.4\res\drawable-watch-v20\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml)
]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

**Updated: My Problem solved and I explained that [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1893).**

Comment: You are using build 23. You can try updating the build tool to 25 from android SDK manager. Also, make sure *Google Play Services* is installed in the SDK Manager.

Comment: @ZayedUpal I updated the build tools and I've installed the latest version of Google play services but the problem doesn't solve.
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
D:\ANDROID\AndroidSDK\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I

Comment: @ZayedUpal I'm using unity 5.3.5p8

Comment: Did you try running from the Unity menu Assets/Google Play Services/Resolve Client Jars? Also, take a look at this link: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/988

Comment: @ZayedUpal I ran the Resolve Client Jars and I got Resolution Complete. Is it true? I tried to build again but I see the same error.

Comment: @ZayedUpal didn't work. Is there any setting for Resolve Client Jar?

Comment: I couldn't find anymore reasons, why it is happening. Normally, it happened to me previously because of the build tools, extras not installed or updated in the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in the internet nothing worked for me.
Here is what that I did to fix this issue.
Not much but don't get mad at me

Step 1: Export all asstets, resources ane everything except google services file. (If you are using multiple Google packages like me eg. Play service, ad seevice, IAP package don't export then). Export as unity package.
Step 2: create a new unity project
Step 3: First import all Google Play packages, don't import your package
Step 4: build and check that the is no error with the empty scene in your new project
Step 5: import your exported package from previous step
Step 6: fix errors in script file due to dependency in Google package
Step 7: build your project

Note: don't move your project to new location it may cause repacking issue again. I don't know why but this occurred to me